# Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause: the Cassandra implementation is always in auto-commit mode

Tags: cassandra, hive, cassandra-jdbc

I am using cassandra 1.2.6 version (Neither datastax cassandra NOR brisk cassandra).

Here I am trying to connect hive 0.9.0 to cassandra 1.2.6.

I get the below error

```
INFO ql.Driver: Starting command: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MyHiveTable
         (m string, n string, o string, p string)
         STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql.CqlStorageHandler'
         TBLPROPERTIES ( "cassandra.ks.name" = "cql3ks",
         "cassandra.cf.name" = "test",
         "cassandra.cql.type" = "text, text, text, text")
13/12/27 17:22:55 INFO exec.DDLTask: Use StorageHandler-supplied org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.serde.cql.CqlSerDe for table MyHiveTable
13/12/27 17:22:55 INFO hive.log: DDL: struct MyHiveTable { string m, string n, string o, string p}
13/12/27 17:22:55 INFO hive.log: DDL: struct MyHiveTable { string m, string n, string o, string p}
13/12/27 17:22:55 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
13/12/27 17:22:55 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
13/12/27 17:22:56 ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin: Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.core.resources" but it cannot be resolved.
13/12/27 17:22:56 ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin: Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.core.runtime" but it cannot be resolved.
13/12/27 17:22:56 ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin: Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.text" but it cannot be resolved.
13/12/27 17:22:56 ERROR Datastore.Schema: Failed initialising database.
Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause: the Cassandra implementation is always in auto-commit mode
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusDataStoreException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause: the Cassandra implementation is always in auto-commit mode
```